# tabla en react desplaza contenido hacia arriba al añadir items, y no deja hacer scroll para visualizar contenido desplazado

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

tengo un crud en react, para añadir poligonos bateeiros, con sus respectivas rias. El problema que tengo es que a medida que añado poligonos a la tabla, el navbar se desplaza hacia arriba y no me deja hacer scroll para bajarlo, de manera que si añado varios poligonos a la tabla, el contenido desplazado hacia arriba va desapareciendo. En la imagen adjunta se ve como el navbar se va desplazando hacia arriba sin posibilidad de hacer scroll.
Es mucho codigo y hay varios componentes en los cuales no se en cual estara el error asi que proporciono el link al repositorio de github:[link al repositorio](https://github.com/palanganero/crudPoligonosBateeirosReact) (para acceder a la tabla hay que logearse con estos datos: `email:natalia.guillan@gmail.com`    `password:1234567`  )

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: si le das clic derecho y pones inspeccionar codigo.. en la ventana element puedes ver las propiedades del dise;o a su totatilidad y los cambios sera mostrados al momento a su version html....

Answer (score 0):

lo he resuelto comentando esta linea en el app.css:

```
body {
  background-color: #fafafa;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  /*height: 100vh;*/
}
```